# How to costomize indent-rainbow settings in vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions, indentation

I installed the extension indent-rainbow and I want to change the settings.

[image: screenshot]

[image: documentation of it]

How can I go to setting code (above picture)?

I've searched indent rainbow at vscode setting but nothing found.